# Appium error : A new session could not be created. (Original error: 'java -version' failed. Error: spawn ENOENT)

Tags: java, eclipse, testing, junit, appium

Code from eclipse : 
public class desiredcapabilities {

```
    @Test
    public void test() throws IOException {
    File appDir = new File("src");
    File app = new File(appDir,"bookMyShow-ucb.apk");

    DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
    cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, MobilePlatform.ANDROID);
    cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "Android Emulator");
    //cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "Android Emulator");
    cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, app.getCanonicalPath());
    AndroidDriver Driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4724/wd/hub"),cap);


    }
```

}

Appium Log :

> Launching Appium server with command: C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node.exe lib\server\main.js --address 127.0.0.1 --port 4724 --session-override --platform-name Android --platform-version 23 --automation-name Appium --log-no-color
>   warn: Appium support for versions of node < 0.12 has been deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Please upgrade!
>   info: Welcome to Appium v1.4.13 (REV c75d8adcb66a75818a542fe1891a34260c21f76a)
>   info: Appium REST http interface listener started on 127.0.0.1:4724
>   info: [debug] Non-default server args: {"address":"127.0.0.1","port":4724,"sessionOverride":true,"logNoColors":true,"platformName":"Android","platformVersion":"23","automationName":"Appium"}
>   info: Console LogLevel: debug
>   info: --> POST /wd/hub/session {"desiredCapabilities":{"app":"C:\Users\sahil\workspace\intro\src\bookMyShow-ucb.apk","platformName":"Android","deviceName":"Android Emulator"}}
>   info: Client User-Agent string: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.1 (Java/1.7.0_79)
>   info: [debug] No appActivity desired capability or server param. Parsing from apk.
>   info: [debug] No appPackage desired capability or server param. Parsing from apk.
>   info: [debug] Using local app from desired caps: C:\Users\sahil\workspace\intro\src\bookMyShow-ucb.apk
>   info: [debug] Creating new appium session 16b1787e-64bd-4bc5-b009-a0a518730ae0
>   error: Failed to start an Appium session, err was: Error: 'java -version' failed. Error: spawn ENOENT
>   info: Starting android appium
>   info: [debug] Getting Java version
>   info: [debug] Cleaning up android objects
>   info: [debug] Cleaning up appium session
>   info: [debug] Error: 'java -version' failed. Error: spawn ENOENT
>       at [object Object]. (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\lib\devices\android\android-common.js:1057:17)
>       at exithandler (child_process.js:633:7)
>       at ChildProcess.errorhandler (child_process.js:649:5)
>       at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
>       at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:795:12)
>   info: [debug] Responding to client with error: {"status":33,"value":{"message":"A new session could not be created. (Original error: 'java -version' failed. Error: spawn ENOENT)","origValue":"'java -version' failed. Error: spawn ENOENT"},"sessionId":null}
>   info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 181.826 ms - 208

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your node version is less than the required for Appium 1.4.13.

```
automation-name Appium --log-no-color warn: Appium support for     versions of node < 0.12
```

Check your node version like this:

```
node --version v0.12.4
```

Comment: Looks like the JDK/Java path is not set properly. Please set the Path properly and execute.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your node click [here](https://davidwalsh.name/upgrade-nodejs)
Should work